# what is a better way to do multithreading

Tags: android

i have an application in which i have a UI activity which is supposed to display data which is retrieved after xml parsing done in another class.
during the xml parsing what i am doing is showing a progressdialog. i pass the handler of my ui activity to the thread doing xml parsing and when parsing is done , the xmlparser therad, using the handler that i have passed dispatches a message which is received by the UI activity after which it starts displaying the data.

the above is how i am doing multithreading.

is there a better way to do the same?
thank you in advance.

Edit: i have heard of the following async task, executionarservice, intent service.
which is the best for my purpose?

Comment: Yes you can go with AsyncTask, and it is the best solution. Check below answers.

Comment: IMHO, message passing concurrency as you are implementing is easier to understand than shared memory concurrency; just be sure that you only have one handler per activity. AsyncTask is an alternative, but post DONUT and pre HONEYCOMB the docs state that AsyncTask uses a thread pool that can result in "parallel execution" errors.

Comment: you can actually get around the Parallel execution errors in java by using mutex, namely the `synchronized (someObjectUsedAsKey) { stuff }`.  This allows you to prevent 2 methods from creating those kinds of errors.  More on that [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) is your best friend if you are doing mutlithreading in android.

Instead of passing runnables to the UI THread, you need to implement a AsyncTask class, and them inside have it parse the xml in doInBackground().

For the progress dialog, initiate the dialog and the show it when onPreExecute() and dismiss it with onPostExecute().  If you want a precentage bar you can implement that in onProgressUpdate()

Comment: ok,i read it but it is saying that i need to add the async task as a subclass of the ui class. but if i want to make a universal class that i can access everytime i need to do some background work. here i am doing that, every time i need to do something i add the handler of the ui and the extra parameters and i start exceuting . so i have one thread class for all the ui classes in my application.

Comment: you do that with the asyncTask... you can pass in a Parameter and just do run() again with the new parameters.  Also the AsyncTask deals with threading on it's own.

Don't forget blocking the UI with the xml parsing action may lock up the UI where it just FC's the app

Comment: no, i am saying that there is activity 1 in which have sublcassed async task. now there is another activity2 which also requries some background work, so i will have to write code for async task for this too.

Comment: you can make it not private, and do `import com.myapp.myactivity.myAsyncTask` to share the class, you can also add new methods like myAsyncTask.setProgDialog(Dialog Dlg) etc.

Comment: ok, i understand that there is a lot of coding reduced with the use of asyntask but what is the difference in the performance when i am using handlers as described in the question?

Comment: If your XML parsing task is quick, there isn't a problem, but if it ever locks up or slows down (large file), then the UI Handler will lock up and your application will Force Close.

Comment: ok, so the logic is if the ui locks up, then its associated handler will also lock up...right?

Comment: close, the UI locks up because the associated handler locked up.
The Android UI Handler (the handler/thread you get from doing `mHandler=Handler()` in an activity is the UI Thread.  This thread, if ever blocked will assume something went wrong and FC the entire application.

`From the user's perspective, the application appears hung. Even worse, if the UI thread is blocked for more than a few seconds (about 5 seconds currently) the user is presented with the infamous "application not responding" (ANR) dialog.`

Comment: ok, got it. so async is the best choice here...plus i will try using it the way you have said over multiple classes.... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Surely there are several techniques for this task.
You can achieve multithreading by using `Services`, `AsyncTasks`, `Handlers`, ...

For taking the right decision based on your problem, i suggest you to take a look at [Romain Guy's Painless Threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) post on Android Developers. This is a very handy article, and very precise as well, never gets old.